# Setting background color in react on basis of props

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

FrameWork: React and TailwindCSS
I have one object and it has some properties.
Object is shown below :

```
const concerns = {
      src: "pregnancy",
      background: "#FF1E34",
      text: "Pregnancy",
      overlay: false,
      widthFull: false,
    },
```

Based on this object I am creating one `div` element as shown below:

```
<div
        className={`${
          concern.background ? `bg-[${concern.background}]` : ""
        } flex justify-end cursor-pointer w-[320px] rounded-2xl  relative ${
          concern.overlay ? "img-overlay" : ""
        } `}
      >
// other code

</div>
```

But this `bg-[${concern.background}]` is not setting up the color. Although when I inspect an element by dev tools and check whether property is setup or not, then it is showing in the dev tools but color is not applying to it.

Here are the images of output and dev tools:
[image: Output Image]

In dev tools you can see that `bg-[#FF1E34]` is there, but styles are not applied
[image: Dev Tool image]

It should look like this:

[image: Required Output]

Based on the the background color prop, it should set the background color. Although I guess it is more of a TailwindCSS issue?

Answer (score 2):

Tailwind checks your files for classes. If class is not found it won't be in the final css file

https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

> Arbitrary values cannot be computed from dynamic values
>
> ❌ `<div class="bg-[{{ userThemeColor }}]"></div>`
>
> Use inline styles for truly dynamic or user-defined values
>
> ✔️ `<div style="background-color: {{ userThemeColor }}"></div>`

In react you should use

```
<div style={{ backgroundColor: concern.background }} />
```

Comment: Thank you!!
Working fine now <3